# What is $\operatorname{Cov}[X+Y]$ when $X$ and $Y$ are NOT independent?

Tags: probability, covariance

I have spent 2 days trying to search a formula that can help me obtain the covariance of (X+Y) especially when X and Y are independent with no luck. I could find for Variance(X+Y) however nothing for covariance. Nor could I find a way to obtain Covariance from Variance.

To the questions, say we have a model
$Z = aX + Y$
Where $X$ has a multivariate dist. with mean $\mu_X$ and $\sigma_X$ 
and $Y$ has a multivariate dist. with mean $\mu_Y$ and $\sigma_Y$ 
and $X$ and $Y$ are NOT independent.

And we were tasked with finding the mean and covariance for $Z$

For the mean, I just added the individual means

$\mu_Z = a*\mu_X + \mu_Y$

However, I am very much stuck for finding covariance for Z which I thought would be the same as $\operatorname{Cov}[aX + Y]$ .  Is there a specific formula that I am missing? Or a property to calculate covariance of addition of 2 dependant variables?

Edit: Covariance of a single Variable as per the book :  *Probabilistic Machine Learning*
[image]

Comment: Covariance is of two variables. $Cov(U,V).$ So what do you mean by $Cov(X+Y)?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I want the $\operatorname{Cov}[Z]$. But $Z = aX + Y$ and hence my question...

Comment: $Z$ is still a single variable, while $Cov$ takes two variables. $Cov[Z]$ is meaningless.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have added source of my textbook, which showed that you can calculate covariance of a single variable $Cov[Z]$

Comment: Just use the properties for variance/covariance componentwise.

Comment: in your textbook $\mathbf x$ is a random vector, not a single random variable.

Comment: (1) that is the covariance matrix of $\mathbf x,$ not the covariance of $\mathbf x,$ and (2) they use bold-face and lower case for $\mathbf x$ to differentiate it from a random variable.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a definition for covariance between two random vectors.

If $\boldsymbol X=(X_1,\ldots,X_m)^T$ and $\boldsymbol Y=(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)^T$ are $m\times 1$ and $n\times 1$ random vectors respectively, then we define [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-covariance_matrix) between $\boldsymbol X$ and $\boldsymbol Y$ as the $m\times n$ matrix $\operatorname{Cov}(\boldsymbol X,\boldsymbol Y)$ whose $(i,j)$th entry is $\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,Y_j)$.

If $E(\boldsymbol X)=\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ and $E(\boldsymbol Y)=\boldsymbol{\beta}$ are the mean vectors,  then it follows that

$$\operatorname{Cov}(\boldsymbol X,\boldsymbol Y)=E\left[(\boldsymbol X-\boldsymbol{\alpha})(\boldsymbol Y-\boldsymbol{\beta})^T\right]$$

The variance-covariance matrix or dispersion matrix of $\boldsymbol X$ is defined as

$$\operatorname{Var}(\boldsymbol X)=\operatorname{Cov}(\boldsymbol X,\boldsymbol X)=E\left[(\boldsymbol X-\boldsymbol{\alpha})(\boldsymbol X-\boldsymbol{\alpha})^T\right]$$

If $\boldsymbol X$ and $\boldsymbol Y$ are random vectors of same dimension and $a,b$ are real numbers, then using the above definition, one can show that

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(a\boldsymbol X+b\boldsymbol Y)&=\operatorname{Cov}(a\boldsymbol X+b\boldsymbol Y,a\boldsymbol X+b\boldsymbol Y)
\\&=a^2\operatorname{Var}(\boldsymbol X)+b^2\operatorname{Var}(\boldsymbol Y)+ab(\operatorname{Cov}(\boldsymbol X,\boldsymbol Y)+\operatorname{Cov}(\boldsymbol Y,\boldsymbol X))
\end{align}